# codeigniter upload multiple file different directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my form have 3 file upload input option.

bot are going to different directory. I can work with one directory but not work with multiple.

My code

```
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/video';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'flv|mov|m4v|mp4';
        $config['max_size'] = '30720';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
        $video_upload=$this->upload->data();

        $config2['upload_path'] = './uploads/video';
        $config2['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|bmp|png';
        $config2['max_size'] = '30720';
        $config2['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config2);
        $this->upload->do_upload('thumbnail1');
        $thumbnail_upload=$this->upload->data();
```

here video file upload successfully but image file not upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->load->library()` doesn't reload or reinitialize the library if it's already loaded.

In this case, you need to modify the existing loaded library options:

```
$this->upload->initialize($config2);
```

instead of

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config2);
```

Should do the trick.